# unresponsive GUI when clicking QTreeWidgetItem - After upgrade pyqt5 from 5.10 to 5.11

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreewidget

The Gui is unresponsived when I click `QTreeWidgetItem` in `QTreeWidget` in Pyqt5 5.11.3.
The code worked in Pyqt5 5.10.1.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDesktopWidget, QMainWindow, QTreeWidget, QTreeWidgetItem


class DeviceTree(QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DeviceTree, self).__init__()
        self.root = QTreeWidgetItem(self)
        self.root.setText(0, "sssss")
        self.root.setCheckState(0, 1)


class MainUi(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainUi, self).__init__()
        self.width = 1000
        self.height = 600
        screen_geometry = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
        self.setGeometry((screen_geometry.width() - self.width) / 2,(screen_geometry.height() - self.height) / 2,
                         self.width, self.height)
        self.setCentralWidget(DeviceTree())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_ui = MainUi()
    main_ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In `PyQt5 5.10.1`, the code works will. I can click the item as long as I wish.
But in `PyQt5 5.11.3`, after click one or more times, the GUI is unresponsive.
How to make it works in `PyQt5 5.11.3`?

Comment: Code is a completed example now.

Comment: Probably a bug of that version, try PyQt5 5.12.2.

Comment: Same problem in 5.12.2.

Comment: I have tested it with PyQt 5.12.2 in Linux and it works correctly, is that all the code that generates the error?

Comment: It shall be environment problem. I tested it in another PC (same os: win7 64), it works correctly. But I don't know the difference between 2 PC. Is there any way to debug it?